# Accessing user name in the socket controller method while Integrating spring security with spring websocket and

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am implementing spring web socket into our web application and I want to access the user name in the socket controller method but I am getting it as null.

Here is the code

```
@MessageMapping("/user/sockettest" )
@SendTo("/topic/sockettestresult")
public String sockAdd(ListId[] listIds) {
    ..
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    return stringRet;
}
```

The spring-security xml looks like this

```
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/topic/**" access="permitAll" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />

    <sec:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/user/home" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="denied/*" access="permitAll" />

    <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
</sec:http>
```

The socket configuration looks like this

```
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/user/sockettest">
    <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>

    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>

    <websocket:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean id="mappingJackson2MessageConverter" class="org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"></property>
        </bean>
    </websocket:message-converters>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

I have looked at some examples and most of them are in java config, however the problem that I have with that is that when I use java config, it is adding an extra /info to the destination url and it is not even connecting to the socket so I am taking the xml route.

I am pretty new to spring web sockets and I am thinking that I am missing something while integrating it with spring security but that's just me. Let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access current user by adding `java.security.Principal` parameter to socket controller method.

```
@MessageMapping("/user/sockettest" )
@SendTo("/topic/sockettestresult")
public String sockAdd(ListId[] listIds, Principal principal) {
    //do whatever you want 
    return stringRet;
}
```

[docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-authentication)